# Trying to link C++ library with C# using swig - will not let me add reference to resulging dll to C# project

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, swig

I'm trying to make c# bindings for a library.  I used cmake to create a visual studio 2010 solution from the library source, and that compiled fine.  I used the included `.i` file to create the wrappers as per the instructions here (https://code.google.com/p/labstreaminglayer/source/browse/LSL/liblsl-Generic/AUTOGENERATE%20HOWTO.txt ) using cygwin.  I then added the resulting liblsl_warp.cxx file to the same project.  It still compiled fine, so I would assume that the resulting `.dll` includes the required bindings.

I've added that project to my c# application and am trying to add a reference from the c# project to the resulting dll (also tried adding a reference to the project).  The only error I get is `A reference to 'lsl' could not be added.`.

What steps am I missing?  I looked at a couple examples, and I am basically setup the same way, but their examples are significantly easier.

Answer (score 1):

SWIG produces both C# and C++ source code.  The C# code uses DllImport to import the functions from the C++ side - it doesn't use .net-like bindings.  Therefore the C++ DLL does not need to be (and cannot be) registered, and hence can't be 'referenced'.  Referencing is for registered DLLs.

So you have a C++ DLL and a C# exe.  Just ensure the C++ DLL can be found by the exe, by putting it in the same folder for example.  Don't worry about referencing it.